# The fabulous Wenger's Summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics, recreational-mathematics

The user Avery Wenger said he came up with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815652/754030) randomly and I think it's very interesting!

Let $s:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be the **sum of digits** function. Then, Wenger defines $w:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ given by
$$w(n):=\min\{k\in\mathbb N: s^k(n)\;\mbox{has a single digit}\}\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$$

Now comes the really interesting part: the **Wenger's Summation**.
$$W_m:=\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^{n+1}w(n)$$

What is so interesting about it? Its amazingly weird graph!

[image]

As you can see, it behaves very poorly at first, looking kinda bumpy (jumps seem to occur on multiples of powers of ten). Soon, however, the graph starts to look very much like a line! Is this really Wenger's Summation asymptotic behavior? Is there a real constant $\omega$ (the Wenger's Constant) such that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{W_m}{m} = \omega\;?$$
If not, then *what is* Wenger's Summation asymptotic behavior? Can we at least show $(W_m)_m$ to be unbounded?

But of course, this is only the **decimal Wenger's Summation**, since we are taking number in decimal notation! What is so special about $10$, anyway? What about the **binary Wenger's Summation**? Does it behave just as oddly? It actually does worse!

[image]

So, for every possible basis $b$ we have a different Wenger's Summation $(W_m^b)_m$ and a different Wenger's Constant $\omega^b$. Ain't that wonderful? Is it true that, if $a<b$, then $\omega^a>\omega^b$? The alternating signals makes proving all this stuff so awkward.

I'm just amazed about this very innocent looking procedure generating such a beautiful cacophony. It all looks so useless and disconnected to... anything else. Do mathematics even has the tools to answer these questions? If you can find anything interesting about Wenger's Summations, please let me know it!

**Attention:** Be aware Avery Wenger did not call all these mathematical objects by his own name in the original post. I'm the only one responsible for that (Avery, if you are seeing this, thank you for sharing the formidable problem that randomly came to you).

---

Values for the Wenger's Summation were calculated through this rudimentary python script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b = 4 # basis

def w(n):
    ap = 0 # additive persistence
    while n>=b:
        aux = n
        sum = 0
        while aux>0:
            sum+=(aux%b)
            aux//=b
        n = sum
        ap+=1
    return ap

S = 0  # Wenger's summation
W = []
for n in range(100000000):
    S+=w(n)*(-1)**(n+1)
    W.append(S)
```

---

**Update:** A comment pointed out the value $w(n)$ is called the [additive persistence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdditivePersistence.html) of $n$. The sequence $(w(n))_n$ (OEIS [A031286](https://oeis.org/A031286) for base $10$) has some interesting properties. For example, every positive integer appears in it infinitely many times. Furthermore, the first occurrence of $N$ in it (OEIS [A006050](https://oeis.org/A006050) for base $10$) is given by the recurrence formula $a(N)=2\cdot b^{\frac{a(N-1)-1}{b-1}}-1$, so **its always odd**, i.e., $N$ appears for the first time in the Wenger's Summation with a positive sign! This might be a first step in proving its boundlessness.

Also, inspired by the same comment, I decided to add the graph for the **Quartenary Wenger's Summation**, which twists our expectations by trending downwards (until it doesn't anymore)!

[image]

Comment: To be clear, is the main question here "Are there any interesting results about Wenger's summations (of any base)?", or "Does the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{W_n}{n}$ exist?" ? In either case, interesting question.

Comment: @C-RAM I would really like to have anything interesting about Wenger's Summations posted as answer to this question. But, for the sake of eventually choosing an 'accepted answer', we may say its asymptotic behavior is my main curiosity when making this post.

Comment: Strangely, base $4$ is different than all others that I've checked: the function trends upward until turning, oscillating, and going negative around $n=170804$, then continues to trend further negative for $n$ up to $10^7$. (Rather like an upside-down version of the graphs for other bases I've tried.) I haven't found any other base for which the function behaves this way. BTW, $w(n)$ is known in the literature as the **additive persistence** of $n$.

Comment: ... Update to my previous comment: For base $4$, it turns out that around $n=28047251,$ the function becomes positive again (!) and continues trending positive up to $n=10^8.$

Comment: A curiosity: for base $2$, the recursion for the first number with additive persistence $k$ reduces to $a_{k} = 2^{a_{k-1}}-1,$ producing $(a_k)_{k=1,2,\dots}=(2,3,7,127,2^{127}-1,2^{2^{127}-1}-1,\dots).$ The first five terms are prime numbers, and [it is still not known which is the first term that fails to be prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169109/16397).

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize there would be much at all behind that question.